# EMR bootstrap issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

We have updated emr version for emr-5.30.0.Since then we are getting error in bootstrap.
"Terminated with bootstrap error"

If i change version back to emr-5.29.0 it work fine.I am not able to find reason for bootstrap error.

We are creating EMR cluster from step function.

We have changed version emr-5.29.0 to emr-5.30.0 as we are adding managed autoscalling and it supports only after 5.29.0

I checked logs but could not find any proper error message. Please suggest some pointers to troubleshoot this.

Comment: with the upgrade to EMR version 5.30, there are many major upgrades to platforms and services (Python, Hue, Oozie, HBase, Spark) that may cause issue with your custom bootstrap script.

Answer (score 0):

EMR version changes many thing including different applications you select to include like @Snighdhajyoti mentioned for example in `emr 5.29.0` spark had version `2.4.4` and in `emr 5.30.0` spark has version `2.4.5`. You can see the basic list of application changes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html).

But the point is, there can be some application or package that you install or configure in bootstrap scipt manually which might be conflicting with the other updated package.

For logs, bootstrap logs dont appear in cluster logs but are in `stderr logs for your bootstrap action` like below

s3://doc-example-bucket/cluster-id/node/instance-id/bootstrap-actions/

[This link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-cluster-bootstrap-failed/) provides some more guidance how can you dig down the error, for example

> If you can't determine why the script failed after reviewing the
> stderr logs, modify your script to provide additional debug
> information. For example, set the -ex parameters in the bash script.
> This allows you to view the bash script flow in the bootstrap action
> log files.
>
> Note: If the failed bootstrap action isn't a bootstrap action that you
> created (for example, if you created six bootstrap actions and the
> error message is "bootstrap action 7 failed with non-zero exit code"),
> it indicates that Amazon EMR couldn't install applications or start
> services. This problem is rare. To resolve this issue, try launching
> the cluster again.